# More than one ArcEngine GeoProcessor run at a time (concurrent)

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing, .net, arcgis-engine

I'm trying to run more than one AddRastersToMosaicDataset geoprocessor at the same from a test .NET 4.8 C# console application. So far I tried the below approach running in threads but it seems as if there's some esri queuing mechanism that is preventing them from running at the same time, their GP messages start times show they run in consecutive order rather than in parallel. So is this the case that only one of these ArcEngine geoprocessors can be run at a time?

BTW I have noticed the geoprocessor type has an ExecuteAsync method but I'm having issues getting that working and am not sure if it would even help, would it support running multiple AddRastersToMosaicDataset geoprocessors at once?

Here's the method to run the GP tool -

```
public static String RunAddRastersToMosaicDataset(String mdPath, String dataTemplate, String inputPath)
{

    Geoprocessor geoProcessor = new Geoprocessor();
    AddRastersToMosaicDataset addRastersToMosaicDataset = new AddRastersToMosaicDataset();
    addRastersToMosaicDataset.in_mosaic_dataset = mdPath;
    addRastersToMosaicDataset.raster_type = dataTemplate;
    addRastersToMosaicDataset.input_path = inputPath;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        geoProcessor.Execute(addRastersToMosaicDataset, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("ERROR: Failed to run ArcGIS AddRastersToMosaicDataset GP tool: {0}", ex.Message));
    }

    if (geoProcessor.MessageCount > 0)
    {
        for (int Count = 0; Count <= geoProcessor.MessageCount - 1; Count++)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(geoProcessor.GetMessage(Count));
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Here is how I called the method to run in background threads -

```
String thread1_out = null;
String thread2_out = null;
String thread3_out = null;

Task task1 = Task.Run(() => thread1_out = RunAddRastersToMosaicDataset(md1Path, "CIB", inPath));

Task task2 = Task.Run(() => thread2_out = RunAddRastersToMosaicDataset(md2Path, "CIB", inPath));

Task task3 = Task.Run(() => thread3_out = RunAddRastersToMosaicDataset(md3Path, "CIB", inPath));


Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Jobs...");
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

Console.Write(thread1_out + "\n");
Console.Write(thread2_out + "\n");
Console.Write(thread3_out + "\n");
```

Comment: Don't know if this is of any help but that tool supports parallel processing, its an [environment property](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-rasters-to-mosaic-dataset.htm#ESRI_GPENVIRONMENT_B4204BADEB8A47C19679987CDA994379) of the tool?

Comment: Did you try Parallel.ForEach instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102966/parallel-foreach-vs-task-run-and-task-whenall#comment42150162_19103047

Comment: Also this, https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#HowToRunALocalGeoprocessingToolAsynchronously.htm